# Progress bar is not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, progress-bar

I am using progress bar to show the progress of files which are being uploaded. When I upload 4 files, the progress bar stops at 25% i.e after 1 for loop iteration. It doesn't get updated as the loop runs.
Here is the JavaScript code which i used.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateProgress(percentage) {
      var value = document.getElementById("pbar");
      value.value = percentage;
  }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="formbody" align="center">
   <table style="width: 367px">
       <tr>
           <td>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Path:"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtpath" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Button2_Click1"/>
           </td>
       </tr>

   </table>
    <br /><br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><progress id="pbar" width="70" max="100" min="0"></progress>
                </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

This is my c# code where the progress bar feature is implemented

```
private void SaveXml(string search)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpath.Text))
    {
       // double val = 0;
        double count = 0;
        int i = 1;
        string temp=@"c:\Results";
        string foldername = @"c:\";
        if (Directory.Exists(temp))
        {
            Directory.Delete(temp, true);
        }

        string pathstring = Path.Combine(foldername, "Results");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathstring);

        string file = txtpath.Text.ToString();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(file);

        int length = files.Length;


        foreach (string eachfile in files)
        {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(eachfile);
            //Response.Write(file);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(eachfile);
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            foreach (XmlNode n in doc)
            {
                if (n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
                {
                    doc.RemoveChild(n);
                }
            }


            string JsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);            
            JObject j = JObject.Parse(JsonText);

            string str = j.ToString();
            str = str.Replace(@"\r", " ");
            str = str.Replace(@"\n", " ");


            string newfile="JS"+i+".json";

                var directory = new DirectoryInfo(pathstring);
                var filecreated = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(directory.FullName, newfile));

                    //File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Results/" + newfile, JsonText);
                    using (Stream stream = filecreated.OpenWrite())
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) 
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(str);
                    }


                i++;
                //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"","", true);
                double val = (100 / length) + count;
                count += val;
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "updateProgress", "updateProgress('" + val.ToString() + "');", true);
                //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        //val = length / 100;


        Delete();
        InsertintoDB(@"c:\Results");
        //string updateProgress = "18";
        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "updateProgress", "updateProgress('" + updateProgress + "');", true);

        }



    else
    {
        Response.Write("No files found");
    }
}
```